# VSS's 'Projects Sharing File' option in Git

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-sourcesafe

I am working on the VSS to Azure DevOps Git migration.

In VSS, I noticed there is an option (right click on the file --> Properties --> Links) which shows the list of other projects using the same file (not reference, but same file copied in all other projects folders).

In the below example, frmOrderList.frm exists in Logistics, Order Administrator and Planning project folders.

[image]

With this option, when developer makes any changes to the frmOrderList.frm in Logistics application, similar changes will be done in other 2 project files.

May I know, is there a similar feature available in Azure DevOps GIT Repo ?

Note:- I know, this is not at all a good option to have a same file in multiple folders (instead - common files can be maintained in the centralized folder and all other solutions can refer from there). Due to time constraints, I am looking for the similar feature in GIT.

Appreciate your response, thank you

Comment: *Git* does not have this feature. Other add-ons like AzDO might; obviously VSS does.

Comment: thanks @torek-- i moved all shared files to centralized location and changed the file reference paths in the solution.